# java translate rectangle 2D

Tags: java, translate

I want to translate a rectangle 2D using a double x and double y. It seems that rectangle2D does not support the translate method. What is the appropriate method to use?

Comment: For all operations, check this [link](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.geom/transform-translation-and-rotation.html)

Comment: More information and a little bit of code could help remove any ambiguities from your question. Are you referring to a java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double object? Is there a reason you cannot simply add to the X or Y values? Not exactly sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it to remain a Rectangle2D, you might have to write your own custom method that just adds to the x and y.

You can also perform arbitrary transformations with an AffineTransform, but this will turn it into a generic Shape (since that transformation might make it no longer rectangular).

```
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty);
Shape transformed = at.createTransformedShape(rectangle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the old `Graphics` variable to `Graphics2D` which has double methods. Mostly double parameters are used.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.translate(3.0, 4.0);
```

Double rectangles are **not available** in Graphics2D (like in `drawRect`). They are available however for own programming as `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double`.